# How to include graphics in minimal code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

[UPDATE]

I'm sorry, if my question is less clear. I mean is how to simplify the writing of syntax in main.tex to display images with the same settings,

```
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Pictures/pic1.png}
    \caption{Picture 1}
    \label{fig:pic1}
    \end{figure}
```

with just write, maybe,

```
    \includegraphics[caption,label]{pic1.png}
```

[ORIGINAL QUESTION]

I am writing an ebook that contains some of graphics. Some of them generated by code (using TikZ), for example `pic1.tex`. I think it will be easier to edit if they save in a separated file. I drop all graphics in a folder named Pictures. I named all graphics with the same prefix `pic`, for example pic2.png, pic3.jpg, etc.

How to include them with a minimal code, say:

```
    \include{pic1.tex}
```

Than

```
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Pictures/pic1.tex}
    \caption{Picture 1}
    \label{fig:pic1}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: If you don't want/need your graphics to float, you don't need to wrap them in a `figure` environment. You can just use the `includegraphics` command, thus saving some typing. Wether that's very useful is another different question :)

Comment: `\include` is for bigger pieces of text and it always emits a `\clearpage`, so it's definitely not good for such usages; `\input` is what you're looking for.

Comment: `\includegraphics` is for embedding driver dependent ***non***-TeX graphic files (Postscript, PDF, PNG, etc.), which are not processed by TeX. TikZ code is TeX code and needs to be digested by TeX. Therefore `\inlcudegraphics` doesn't work here.

Comment: @AlexG: Oh, I didn't know that includegraphics can't be used for TikZ code ... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be a best practitioner, consider the following.
Let your files and folders hierarchy be as follows.

[image]

- `main.tex` in `Project`.
- `rules.jpg` is in `SubDir`.
- `behaviors.jpg` is in `ParentSiblingDir`.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{SubDir/}{../ParentSiblingDir/}}

\newcommand\Insert[5][hbtp]{%
    \begin{figure}[#1]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[#2]{#3}
        \caption{#4}
        \label{#5}
    \end{figure}}


\begin{document}
\Insert{scale=.2}{behaviors}{Students' behaviors}{fig:behaviors}
\Insert{scale=.2}{rules}{Father's rules}{fig:rules}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Remarks:

- Use `\graphicspath` to register folders (directories) from which the images will be included or imported. The format is `\graphicspath{{<relative path1>}{<relative path2>}{<relative path...>}}`. Each path must be followed by `/`.
- The remaining code should be clear enough!

Comment: @EdyJo: If you are satisfied with this answer, please accept it by clicking the check mark button (below the down vote button). You can optionally up vote it as well. Terima kasih.